# tablesorter Update a value in a column

Tags: tablesorter

I have a TableSorter object with 5 columns. The forth one is a checkbox and the fifth one is a total, so numbers.

What I want to do is to change the value of my Total when I click on the checkbox on the same row. So how can I access the value of a specific column of the row I'm clicking on the checkbox ? I'm sure there is a simple way of doing it ! ;-)

Thanks !

FoG

Comment: Could you share some code or a demo. I would have done it but I have no idea where the total value for the row is coming from - from the checked cell in that row only? Are you totaling all checked cells?

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the updateCell method to update a single table cell... I would not recommend using "updateAll" unless you are changing the contents of the .

```
var $cell = $('#myTarget');
$cell.html('some new data');
$('table').trigger('updateCell', [ this, resort, callback ]
```